# Make cookie secure

Tags: security, cookies, addition, max-age

Need to add max-age to

```
document.cookie = "up=upv; SameSite=None; Secure";
```

IE

```
document.cookie = "up=upv;max-age=" + (60*60*24*30) + ";"

document.cookie = "up=upv;max-age=" + (60*60*24*30) + ";"
```

Comment: This does not work.document.cookie = "up=upv; SameSite+None; Secure";max-age=" + (60*60*24*30) + ";"

Comment: I dont get a typo error with this but still get the Samesite attributre error in inspector<br>  document.cookie = "up=upv;{ secure: true }+max-age=" + (60*60*24*30) + ";"